# SDL Window shows final frame from the last time the program was run in the background of a new window when I start up a new instance

Tags: sdl-image

I'm making a simple game and just messing around with SDL. I have two images currently, and I am practicing making them the background. I make one the background by calling RenderCopy, the DestroyTexture to clear it from memory, and then I present it. I changed the file path from one image to the other to change the background. I ran the program, and now the new image is **layered on top of the other**. I can fix this problem if I manually do a clean of my computer's memory, and it renders properly. For some reason, SDL is not clearing the image called previously. There is no mention of the old image anywhere else in the code, and all the Destroy functions are called. What is going on?

Edit: I did a little bit of snooping and its not that it even loads the old image; whatever the final render displayed on any program running SDL was before it was run, it will be the background. It is literally like a TV burning an image into the screen; its always there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by simply clearing the frame between frames. Didn't have any performance impact.